# SVG clipping using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

We are trying to use clippath for polyline using javascript.
We tried writing a sample HTML code which worked fine:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="parent">
    <clippath id="cut-off-bottom">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" />
    </clippath>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" />
</svg>
```

This works absolutely fine.

But when we try to generate the same code using javascript it doesn't work:

```
_svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
parent = document.getElementById('parent');

circle = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'circle');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', '100');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', '100');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '100');

clippath = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'clippath');
clippath.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'clip');

r = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'rect');
r.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '0');
r.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '0');
r.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '200');
r.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100');


clippath.appendChild(r);

circle.setAttributeNS(_svgNS, 'clip-path', 'url(#clip)');
parent.appendChild(clippath);
parent.appendChild(circle);
```

Can anyone please help us find the issue with the above code...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are setting the wrong id on your clippath, but unfortunately that doesn't fix it.

Comment: BTW, you should probably `var` your variables instead of making them globals, etc. `var clippath = …;`

Comment: I've set up a fiddle but can't get it to work :/ .. http://jsfiddle.net/F4mq9/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After a while of fiddling it turns out that SVG is very case-sensitive and the `clippath` element needs to be a `clipPath` element.

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F4mq9/2/

Very strange that the static sample worked however.

Comment: Chalk it up to the super-permissive case-insensitive nature of HTML5 instead of XHTML.

Comment: Thanks..  I too found the issue when I re-wrote the code without any copy-paste :)

Comment: HTML5 just goes "Yep, that's probably okay", whereas SVG consists of strict XML like behaviour I guess

Comment: I noticed something else strange: if you use jQuery to add the elements, it will ignore capitals in the tagnames and turn them into lower-case letters. 

So $("<clipPath></clipPath>").appendTo(whatever) still only creates a <clippath></clippath> tag. 

The fiddle mentioned above is a great example to do it without jQuery in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2):

You set the `id` of the `<clippath>` to `clip`, but then you set the `clip-path="url(#clippath)`. You need to match the `id` attribute you set.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uMe4s/7/

I've tersified some of your code (appending the element as soon as it was created, instead of at the end). This has no effect on the solution.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. But with proper ID also it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, however the fix was not mentioned in the approved fix. The reason it did not work was because of the namespace on the clippath attribute. Like in the jsfiddle, the namespace url should be set to `null`.